# Kubernetes+Istio - HTTP/1.1 403 Authentication required when using Host entry in CURL

Tags: kubernetes, curl, istio

Facing an issue when accessing a service deployed in AKS through Istio using Host Header.

Below is the configuration for gateway and VirtualService in Istio (based out of the sample from [httpbin](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/release-1.13/samples/httpbin)) and trying to test the sample service using Host Header as given in this URL: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#before-you-begin

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "httpbin.example.com"
    - "40.76.148.29"
    - "52.171.230.140"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
  - "httpbin.example.com"
  - "40.76.148.29"
  - "52.171.230.140"
  gateways:
  - httpbin-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8000
        host: httpbin
```

The issue is that when I access the above service in CURL without host header works fine, whereas including the Host Header throws HTTP 403 error:

curl -s -I "http://52.171.230.140:80/status/200"

[image]

curl -s -I -HHost:httpbin.example.com "http://52.171.230.140:80/status/200"

[image]

Note: There is no Mutual TLS (PeerAuthentication) set on any of the namespaces.

Can someone point if anything is wrong in the setup/steps to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you sure there is no PeerAuthentication set for entire cluster?

Comment: Yes, verified by running "kubectl get peerauthentication" on both the custom namespace and the istio-system namespace.